# Using Data Binding, display time in a textbox based on selected TimeZone in ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am populating my combobox with TimeZone Info using the below in:

> MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ReadOnlyCollection<TimeZoneInfo> TimeZones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
    this.DataContext = TimeZones;
    cmb_TZ.SelectedIndex = 1;
}
```

> The below is from the XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmb_TZ" ItemsSource="{Binding}"   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Height="28.5" Margin="10,65.375,30.945,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftMargin, RightMargin, TopMargin, BottomMargin" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_Selection"/>
```

I am also able to show the corresponding value in a **textbox** by using this code:

```
private void ComboBox_Selection(object Sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var cmbBox = Sender as ComboBox;
    DateTime currTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    TimeZoneInfo tst = (TimeZoneInfo)cmbBox.SelectedItem;
    txt_Time.Text = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(currTime, TimeZoneInfo.Utc, tst).ToString("HH:mm:ss dd MMM yy");
}
```

where txt_Time is my text box. The XAML code for it is :

```
 <TextBox x:Name="txt_Time" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Height="28.5" Margin="26.148,65.375,28.13,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftMargin, RightMargin, TopMargin, BottomMargin"/>
```

> **My question is :**

***Is there a way to accomplish this using Data Binding? 
I am able to do this using the straight forward method shown above. But I was wondering if this calculation could be done via Data Binding?***

I am new to C#/WPF and I tried creating a simple class and also a class using the INotifyPropertyChanged and referring to it in the MainWindow constructor, but I couldn't get even the combobox populated.

I really want to understand and use the Data Binding magic of C#.

Comment: you want to bind all the values in Combobox right?

Comment: The combobox will have a list of timezones and I want to be able to show the corresponding time in the Text Box depending on the timezone I selected in the CB.

Comment: "I really want to understand and use the Data Binding magic of C#." If you really want that, you should go for a solution without any event handlers in code behind, as shown in the other answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a standard MVVM approach you would create a view model class with two properties, one read-only collection for all TimeZoneInfos, and one for the currently selected TimeZone.

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ReadOnlyCollection<TimeZoneInfo> TimeZones { get; }
        = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();

    private TimeZoneInfo selectedTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;

    public TimeZoneInfo SelectedTimeZone
    {
        get { return selectedTimeZone; }
        set
        {
            selectedTimeZone = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedTimeZone"));
        }
    }
}
```

You can set the DataContext of your window to an instance of the view model and bind the ComboBox and TextBox properties like shown in this XAML:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:TimeZoneConverter x:Key="TimeZoneConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding TimeZones}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTimeZone}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedTimeZone,
                        Converter={StaticResource TimeZoneConverter}}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

where the Binding to the Text property uses a Converter like this:

```
public class TimeZoneConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value == null ? string.Empty : TimeZoneInfo
            .ConvertTime(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.Utc, (TimeZoneInfo)value)
            .ToString("HH:mm:ss dd MMM yy");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `ComboBox`, bind its `ItemSource` to `ReadOnlyCollection` ,

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmb_TZ" ItemsSource="{Binding TimeZoneList}"   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Height="28.5" Margin="10,65.375,30.945,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftMargin, RightMargin, TopMargin, BottomMargin" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_Selection"/>
```

Now the time you want to display bind to a property,

```
<TextBox x:Name="txt_Time" Text="{Binding TimeZome}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Height="28.5" Margin="26.148,65.375,28.13,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftMargin, RightMargin, TopMargin, BottomMargin"/>
```

The Corresponding CS file is now,

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }


        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ReadOnlyCollection<TimeZoneInfo> TimeZones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
            TimeZoneList = TimeZones;
            cmb_TZ.SelectedIndex = 1;
        }

        private void ComboBox_Selection(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var cmbBox = sender as ComboBox;
            DateTime currTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            TimeZoneInfo tst = (TimeZoneInfo)cmbBox.SelectedItem;
            TimeZome = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(currTime, TimeZoneInfo.Utc, tst).ToString("HH:mm:ss dd MMM yy");
        }

        private string _TimeZome;
        public string TimeZome
        {
            get { return _TimeZome; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _TimeZome)
                    return;

                _TimeZome = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("TimeZome");
            }
        }
        private ReadOnlyCollection<TimeZoneInfo> _TimeZoneList;
        public ReadOnlyCollection<TimeZoneInfo> TimeZoneList
        {
            get { return _TimeZoneList; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _TimeZoneList)
                    return;

                _TimeZoneList = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("TimeZoneList");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ObjectDataProvider will simplify your code. Just for this question , actually you don't need to write a View Model in CS.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:src="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Core"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="timezone" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:TimeZoneInfo}" MethodName="GetSystemTimeZones"></ObjectDataProvider>
        <local:TimeZoneConverter x:Key="timezoneconverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cmb_TZ" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource timezone}}" Height="30" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="txt_Time" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ElementName=cmb_TZ, Path=SelectedValue, Converter={StaticResource timezoneconverter}}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And also Clemens' Converter is needed.

```
public class TimeZoneConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value == null ? string.Empty : TimeZoneInfo
            .ConvertTime(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.Utc, (TimeZoneInfo)value)
            .ToString("HH:mm:ss dd MMM yy");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```